# Extjs 4.2 changing frame color for panels

Tags: extjs, sass, extjs4.2, sencha-cmd

I am using Sencha CMD to build up my theme package.
I want that my framed panels will have border-radius of 8 pixels and that they will be white.

Here is what I have done:

```
$panel-frame-border-radius: 8px !default;
$panel-frame-border-color: #fff !default;
```

Now I see that the border radius has changed, but its color is still as the ext classic theme (blue).

How can I change this color?

Comment: Check what style is applied first using chrome dev tools

Comment: the applied style is .x-panel-default-framed and currently the the background color is #dfe9f6

Comment: On IE8 a different style is applied, one that has background images...

Comment: check the particular selectors of the applied style and your

Answer (score 0):

Ok , I solved it by adding the following rule

```
$panel-frame-background-color: #FFFFFF !default;
```

Did not realize that this was the appropriate property to use.